# Not getting user input as required in Java

Tags: java

I am new to java but not to programming as I know C++.

I am simply trying to get input from user either of integer or string form but when i execute my program, it just stands still and does nothing until I press enter. 
My program and result after pressing "Enter" is given.

My question is "**why I am not getting user input?**"

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class roomarea
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enterd value is " + input);
        }
    }
```

the result is

```
Start Running math >Command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\java.exe"    
-classpath "C:\Documents and Settings\Ahmad Abdullah\My Documents\NaviCoder IDE for    
Java\projects\math\output\classes";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\rt.jar";    
roomarea 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at
    java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)    at    
    java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)   at    
    java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)    at    
    java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)    at 
    roomarea.main(Main.java:14)  >Run
```

Process Completed

Comment: "why i am not getting user input?" - maybe because you don't enter some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "it just stands still and does nothing untill i press enter", it is doing exactly what you told it to - it is waiting for you to input an `int`. You just hitting enter meant that there was no input, which your scanner could not interpret as an `int`, hence the exception.

If you enter an integer number then press the enter key, your program should work.

Comment: In addition, it might be clearer if you stick in a `System.out.println("Enter an int:");` prompt before your `scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: when i mentioned that i am not new to programming but to java, which in a matter of common sense says "i know what i need to do with my program" but when i do, it doesn't ask. i was entering digits but cursor was just blinking and standing still! well i do appreciate your response. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your program should work if you enter an `int` as input. (By pressing `Enter` while "waiting" for the program, you could arise the exception you're talking about).

If you enter a char for example, you'll get [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) exception:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Comment: Thank you very much Maroun you gave a little idea about exception's reason. now i am working good with java!